# Capture image without user interaction in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to capture image without user knows in iphone. For that i have used custom overlay and called [imagePicker takePicture] but it's not calling didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method. Can anyone help me to solve this issue??

Code:

```
imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
imgPicker.delegate = self; 
imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imgPicker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO; 
imgPicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
imgPicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
imgPicker.view = cameraOverlayView;
[self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES]; 
[imgPicker takePicture];

[imgPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Please help me to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @try
    {

        AVCaptureDevice *frontalCamera;
        NSArray *allCameras = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

        // Find the frontal camera.
        for ( int i = 0; i < allCameras.count; i++ ) {
            AVCaptureDevice *camera = [allCameras objectAtIndex:i];

            if ( camera.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront ) {
                frontalCamera = camera;
            }
        }

        // If we did not find the camera then do not take picture.
        if ( frontalCamera != nil ) {
            // Start the process of getting a picture.
            session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

            // Setup instance of input with frontal camera and add to session.
            NSError *error;
            AVCaptureDeviceInput *input =
            [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:frontalCamera error:&error];

            if ( !error && [session canAddInput:input] ) {
                // Add frontal camera to this session.
                [session addInput:input];

                // We need to capture still image.
                AVCaptureStillImageOutput *output = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];

                // Captured image. settings.
                [output setOutputSettings:
                 [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG,AVVideoCodecKey,nil]];

                if ( [session canAddOutput:output] ) {
                    [session addOutput:output];

                    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
                    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in output.connections) {
                        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
                            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
                                videoConnection = connection;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (videoConnection) { break; }
                    }

                    // Finally take the picture
                    if ( videoConnection ) {
                        [session startRunning];

                        [output captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

                            if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) {
                                NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput 
                                                     jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
                                UIImage *photo = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];  
                                NSLog(@"Captured img====> %@",photo);
                                app.capImg=photo;
                               // [addnewpropertydelegate setSelectedImager:photo];
                               // NSLog(@"selected image::: %@",addnewpropertydelegate);
                            }
                        }];
                    }
                }
            }
        }           
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Camera" message:@"Camera is not available  " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        // [alert release];
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using same code, but getting image with black overlay and image is not clear. Did you apply any other code as well? Can you help with this?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are dismissing the modalViewController straight away, so its not getting chance to call the delegate.

You should call `[imgPicker takePicture]`

and then call the `[imgPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` in the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method.

Comment: Exactly it works. But i don't want that user knows the photo is getting captured.So i have to comment [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES]; Now how can i capture with this functionality?

Comment: Its not possible without presenting the ImagePicker. Atleast not mentioned on any documented APIs avaialble.